# Index of center of mxn matrix. if center does not exist, return the index of the square closest to the center with the highest integer

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Trying to write a method which returns the center of the MxN matrix and if the center does not exist the method should return the index of the square closest to the center with the highest integer value

> Eg 1. -
>
> ```
> [[5, 7, 8, 6, 3],
>  [0, 0, 7, 0, 4],
>  [4, 6, 3, 4, 9],
>  [3, 1, 0, 5, 8]]
> ```
>
> return [1,2] (Center does not exist so closest to the center is [[0,
> 7, 0],[6, 3, 4]] and 7 is the max value)

> Eg 2. -
>
> ```
> [[5, 7, 8, 6],
>  [0, 0, 7, 0],
>  [4, 6, 3, 4],
>  [3, 1, 0, 5]]
> ```
>
> return [1,2] (Center does not exist so closest to center is [[0,7],[6,3]] and 7 is the max value)

> Eg 3. -
>
> ```
> [[5, 7, 8],
>  [0, 0, 7],
>  [4, 6, 3]]
> ```
>
> return [1,1] (Center exists)

```java
private static int[] centerCoordinates(int[][] matrix) {
    int row = matrix.length;
    int col = matrix[0].length;
    if (row % 2 != 0 && col % 2 != 0 && row == col)
        return new int[]{row / 2, col / 2};
    if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0 && row == col) {
        //calculate the max of internal square Eg 2.
        return new int[]{x, y};
    }
    //where row!=col
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you made a mistake in example 1, you gave the right answer, but I think the cells considered should only be [[7],[3]] and not 3 columns wide.

Basically if the dimension is even check length/2-1 and length/2.

If the dimension is odd check only length/2.

Loop through and take max.

```java
private static int[] centerCoordinates(int[][] matrix) {
    int row = matrix.length;
    int col = matrix[0].length;
    int[] ans = new int[]{row/2-(1-(row%2)), col/2-(1-(col%2))};
    int best = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=row/2-(1-(row%2));i<row/2+1;i++){
        for(int j=col/2-(1-(col%2));j<col/2+1;j++){
            if(matrix[i][j]>best){
                best = matrix[i][j];
                ans = new int[]{i,j};
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case the center point exists only for those matrices where `m == n` and both are odd numbers. If this condition is not met, then take central region `(m, n)`:

- even - from `x / 2` to `length - x / 2`
- odd - from `x / 2 - 1` to `length - x / 2 + 1`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m1 = {
            {5, 7, 8, 6, 3},
            {0, 0, 7, 0, 4},
            {4, 6, 3, 4, 9},
            {3, 1, 0, 5, 8}};
    int[][] m2 = {
            {5, 7, 8, 6},
            {0, 0, 7, 0},
            {4, 6, 3, 4},
            {3, 1, 0, 5}};
    int[][] m3 = {
            {5, 7, 8},
            {0, 0, 7},
            {4, 6, 3}};

    int[][] cr1 = centralRegion(m1);
    int[][] cr2 = centralRegion(m2);
    int[][] cr3 = centralRegion(m3);

    Arrays.stream(cr1).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    // [0, 7, 0]
    // [6, 3, 4]
    System.out.println(maxValue(cr1)); // 7

    Arrays.stream(cr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    // [0, 7]
    // [6, 3]
    System.out.println(maxValue(cr1)); // 7

    Arrays.stream(cr3).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    // [0]
}
```

```java
public static int[][] centralRegion(int[][] arr) {
    if (arr.length == arr[0].length && arr.length % 2 != 0) {
        return new int[][]{{arr[arr.length / 2][arr[0].length / 2]}};
    } else {
        return Arrays.stream(arr, cp(arr.length), arr.length - cp(arr.length))
              .map(row -> Arrays
                    .stream(row, cp(row.length), row.length - cp(row.length))
                    .toArray())
              .toArray(int[][]::new);
    }
}
```

```java
public static int cp(int length) {
    return length / 2 - length % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

```java
public static int maxValue(int[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).max().getAsInt();
}
```